# is there something faster than Enumerable.Except<TSource> Method?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I have a program that downloads data from server database to client database. server database keeps growing recently.

in that program, there is an option to select download all data OR download data for a specific time period (can select backward days from today). if the user selects all, I wrote the program to truncate client database table and insert all data using bulk copy. that part is ok.

but the problem is when user select a specific time period (each recode has created data time ) program has to compare two tables and divide recodes (server data) in two tables. one is, not exist data and the second one is not existing data. and what I'm going to do is, 
not existing data directly insert into client DB (i'm using bulk insert) and Existing data inserting into a tempory table using bulkcopy and after update client's table using the above tempory table. My actual problem occurs when dividing server's table. this is how I did it

```
 updateTable = (From c In dt_from_server.AsEnumerable() 
                Join o In Dt_from_client.AsEnumerable() 
                On c.Field(Of String)("BARCODE").Trim() Equals o.Field(Of String)("BARCODE").Trim() 
                And c.Field(Of String)("ITEM_CODE").Trim() Equals o.Field(Of String)("ITEM_CODE").Trim() 
                Select c).CopyToDataTable()

 insertTable = dt_server.AsEnumerable()
    .Except(updateTable.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
    .CopyToDataTable()
```

(normally there is over 1M recodes in the server table )

when there is over 1 Milion recodes, Update part taking acceptable time like 10 minutes (Yes it taking 5GB space from Ram - in this case, it's ok when considering performance )
but insert part seams taking days, just to assing the insertTable(datatable). this is the issue.
`AsEnumerable().Except()` part taking long time and I couldn't find a solution speedup this process. I'm not sure I explained this correctly. Could anyone can give me some advice for this?

Comment: One improve is to not use `DataRowComparer.Default` because this will compare all values of a `DataRow` with all values of another `DataRow`. Are `dt_from_server` and `dt_server` same DataTables? If so you could use reference equality comparison.

Comment: You should not process all data at once but only parts of it, isn't it possible?

Comment: yes dt_from_server and dt_server is same datatable.

Comment: I'm not sure it can break into pats (if there then how?). what i need is insertTable = (dt_server - updateTable)

Comment: Do you have some key fields which can let you not to compare all fields in these tables?

Comment: i can get updateTable part. but i can't get insertTable as updateTable

Comment: I'm not sure how to put a condition into Except method

Comment: @SupunRathnayaka: edited my anaswer below

Comment: hello, @TimSchmelter Schmelter, Your answer was correct. I had some issue, it didn't work first time. I don't understand why. but the program was in .net framework 2.0 and I turned it into 4.5 it didn't work. (may be old project had some issue) so created new project and i put old source there. then it started to working :D. I was confused with hall thing and that why I unable to mark your answer as the correct answer.I can't see your answer anymore. can you put it back? thank you for your time, your solution is really worked as I expected.it divided 1.39 million recodes in 4 mins.thanks again

Comment: Much Appreciate !!

Comment: I've undeleted my answer now. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have commented that  `dt_from_server` and `dt_server`  are actually the same `DataTable` you don't need to compare all values of all `DataRows` with each other, which is what `DataRowComparer.Default` does. You can use `Except` without second parameter for the comparer, then only references are compared which is much faster.

You also don't need two `CopyToDataTable` which creates two additonal big `DataTables` in memory, process the rows one after the other.

Here is a different approach using Linq's left-outer join, which is more efficient:

```
Dim query = from rServ in dt_from_server.AsEnumerable()
            group join rClient in Dt_from_client.AsEnumerable()
            On New With{
                Key .BarCode = rServ.Field(Of String)("BARCODE").Trim(),
                Key .ItemCode = rServ.Field(Of String)("ITEM_CODE").Trim()
            } Equals New With{
                Key .BarCode = rClient.Field(Of String)("BARCODE").Trim(),
                Key .ItemCode = rClient.Field(Of String)("ITEM_CODE").Trim()
            }   into Group
            From client In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()  
            Select new With { .ServerRow = rServ, .InsertRow = client is Nothing }

Dim insertOrUpdateRows = query.ToLookup(Function(x) x.InsertRow, Function(x) x.ServerRow)
Dim insertRows = insertOrUpdateRows(true).CopyToDataTable()  'CopyToDataTable redundant if you process rows immediately now' 
Dim updateRows = insertOrUpdateRows(false).CopyToDataTable() 'CopyToDataTable redundant if you process rows immediately now'
```

But in general the most scalable and efficient approach would be to not load all into memory at once and then process all, but to use database paging(or a stored-procedure) to process only parts of it in memory, otherwise it's likely that you will encounter a `OutOfMemoryException` sooner or later.

---

C# as requested:

```
var query = from rServ in dt_from_server.AsEnumerable()
            join rClient in Dt_from_client.AsEnumerable()
            on new { BarCode = rServ.Field<string>("BARCODE").Trim(), ItemCode = rServ.Field<string>("ITEM_CODE").Trim() }
            equals new { BarCode = rClient.Field<string>("BARCODE").Trim(), ItemCode = rClient.Field<string>("ITEM_CODE").Trim() } 
            into clientGroup
            from client in clientGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { ServerRow = rServ, InsertRow = client == null };

var insertOrUpdateRows = query.ToLookup(x => x.InsertRow, x => x.ServerRow);
var insertRows = insertOrUpdateRows[true].CopyToDataTable();  // CopyToDataTable redundant if you process rows immediately now
var updateRows = insertOrUpdateRows[false].CopyToDataTable(); // CopyToDataTable redundant if you process rows immediately now
```

Comment: "Public member 'ToLookup' on type '<SelectManyIterator>d__22(Of VB$AnonymousType_0(Of DataRow,IEnumerable(Of DataRow)),DataRow,VB$AnonymousType_2(Of DataRow,Boolean))' not found. " this exception occurs when reach here   `Dim insertOrUpdateRows = query.ToLookup(Function(x) x.InsertRow, Function(x) x.ServerRow)`

Comment: `Enumerable.ToLookup` is there since .NET 3.5, strange. What .NET version? Have you added `Imports System.Linq`?

Comment: @Viranjakaushalya: added